# reading and writing to a json file, but it's not working

Tags: node.js

When I try to read, update and write to the same json file it's not actually overwriting the old file. Can anyone give me a solution on how to fix this, I would be very gratefull.

```
const fs = require('fs');
var json = require('./test.json');
json['hello'] = "hi"

var options = { flag : 'w' };
fs.writeFile('test.json', JSON.stringify(json), options, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
});
```

Comment: Presumably it's not throwing an error. This code works fine and updates the JSON file for me. Any chance you're looking at the wrong test.json file?

Comment: No it doesn't update for me. How strange that it updates for you. How did you execute it? made an empty test.json file before executing?

Comment: I would search your hard drive for test.json. Or modify the code to write to xyz.json temporarily and re-test. I'm using, as you would expect, `node app.js` in the folder containing the JSON file. The JSON file exists prior to the run. It contains trivial JSON properties.